# How to load value with dynamic key place holder in spring batch?

Tags: spring, spring-batch

Spring Batch: How to get value from property file if key is generated dynamically from input parameter

**propertyfile content**:
my.table.book.bic.code=11111
my.table.news.bic.code=22222

**Spring batch configuration**

< property name="bicCodeValue"  value="#{jobParameters['inputTable'] + '.bic.code'}" />

**Where inputTable is input parameter for batch**
inputTable = my.table.book
inputTable = my.table.news

I am not getting value from property file instead of value from property file I am getting only key in code "my.table.book.bic.code".

**I need to update only in xml file like**

**< property name="bicCodeValue"  value="#{jobParameters['inputTable'] + '.bic.code'}"  / >**

But this is not working.

Comment: I need to update only in xml file like 
< property name="bicCode"  value="#{jobParameters['inputTable'] + '.bic.code'}"  / >
But this is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You could inject an instance of

```
@Autowired
private Environment env;
```

and then do something like:

```
env.getProperty("my.table."+inputTable+".book.bic.code")
```

Comment: I need to update only in xml file like 
< property name="bicCode"  value="#{jobParameters['inputTable'] + '.bic.code'}"  / >
But this is not working.

Answer (score 0):

According to your properties, the SpEL expression `jobParameters['inputTable']` should return a `String` value, so you can try to use the `concat` method in your expression:

`<property name="bicCodeValue" value="#{jobParameters['inputTable'].concat('.bic.code')}" />`

For more details about SpEL, please see here: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#expressions

Comment: But it will treat this key as its value, but I need to convert this value as key/placeholder and value should be picked up from property file using this key.

Comment: in this case you probably need to wrap the SpEL expression with `${}`. Have you tried `value="${\" #{ jobParameters['inputTable'].concat('.bic.code') } \"}"` ?